# Nominal Categories: Cat and Dog Breeds - overlapping categories

Tags: python, scikit-learn, categorical-data

I have some data, say pictures of dogs and cats, and labels for them. The vast majority of my samples are labeled by breed (German Shepherd, Domestic short hair, etc.), but a few just have a Cat or Dog label. I would like to use something like OneHotEncoder to make these nice categorical values for classification. My problem is that I would like everything that is labeled as an actual dog breed to also register as a dog, and the same for the cats.

For example:
If I have this DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Breed':['Cat', 'German Shepherd', 'Scottish Fold', 'Tiger',
                       'Domestic Shorthair', 'Cat', 'Dog']},
                    index=['Mr. Snuffles', 'Pookie', 'Grumpagus', 'Cuddles',
                       'Steve', 'Boots', 'Santas Little helper'])
```

and then I run the OneHotEncoder:

```
ohe = OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False)
ohe.fit_transform(df)
```

I get something like:

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

with `ohe.categories_` of:

```
[array(['Cat', 'Dog', 'Domestic Shorthair', 'German Shepherd',
        'Scottish Fold', 'Tiger'], dtype=object)]
```

but I would like:

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Is there an encoder that I can do this with or do I need to do some custom mapping?